# Move a sidebar in CSS

Tags: html, css, sidebar

```css
.wrapper{
    width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
}
.left-sidebar {
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 200px;
    background: #303030;
    height:100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#sidebar {
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: #303030;
    color: #fff;
    position:fixed;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    z-index:999;
    height:100%;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-sidebar">
    <nav id="sidebar">
```

I would like to move this sidebar to the most left and top.

I have tried to remove padding but there is no padding so it did nothing.

How can I move the side bar to the most left and the most top?

Comment: Your css would be useful here also. Even better? Create a workable demo for other's to test.

Comment: This is not the way you ask a question on SO, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `position: fixed`. Simply set the `top` and `left` css property to 0 within your nav sidebar container.

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
}
.left-sidebar {
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 200px;
    background: #303030;
    height:100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#sidebar {
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: #303030;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    z-index: 999;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-sidebar">
    <nav id="sidebar">
```